# How to multiply the elements of a column in a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

i have a 2D array 3X5 and i need the to multiply each element in column one, and so forth. This is what ive attempted without any luck. the result is not correct. i tried storing each column into an array and multiply each element from that array but i get the same results.

edit: yes i am aware there is no multiplication in this code, that is because it yields an incorrect product.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        double v = 0.0;
        double[] ex = new double[3];
        double volumeBox1 = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            v = d[i][j];
            System.out.println(v);

            for(int z = 0; z < 3; z++){
                ex[z] = v;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The volume of box " + (j+1) + " is: " + volumeBox1);
```

Comment: Where is the multiplication in your code ?

Comment: You do know that you're not actually doing any multiplying in your code? `volumeBox1` is always 0.

Comment: try writing down on paper (or in comments in an IDE) the steps you want to perform, then the code for each step underneath. Should help you see were you are going wrong, for example, there is no multiplication occurring in your code

Answer (score 2):

I will assume your matrix is 5 x 3, which is more logical and convenient than 3 x 5 for this use case :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < d.length ; j++) {
     double vol = 1;
     for (int j = 0 ; j < d[i].length ; j++) {
         vol *= d[i][j];
     }
     System.out.println("The volume of box " + (j + 1) + " is: " + vol);
}
```

This can of course be done with a 3 x 5 matrix but I think it makes less sense to iterate on the columns :

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < d[0].length ; j++) {
     double vol = 1;
     for (int i = 0 ; i < d.length ; i++) {
         vol *= d[i][j];
     }
     System.out.println("The volume of box " + (j + 1) + " is: " + vol);
}
```